# Ways to Speed Up a Lookup Function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I created a lookup function that finds the result from a separate tab within the same worksheet with 4 different fields to match.

When running, this takes entirely too long to complete (to the point where I have to kill the macro run). I need to build the same lookup function for 8 different fields, based on the exact same match criteria. Any advice on how to speed up this query or build it in a more dynamic way, so I can lookup all 8 columns at once rather than building functions and subs for each lookup field?

```vb
    Function fcst_bal_find(ByVal Anode As String, ByVal LoB As String, ByVal Month As String, ByVal Year As String) As Variant

        Dim Fcst_Essbase As Worksheet
        Dim fcst_rowcnt
        Dim act_rowcnt
        
        fcst_rowcnt = Sheets("Date Dims").Range("B7")
        act_rowcnt = Sheets("Date Dims").Range("B8")
        Set Fcst_Essbase = Sheets("Fcst Essbase Pull")


        For i = 2 To fcst_rowcnt + 4
            If WorksheetFunction.Trim(Fcst_Essbase.Cells(i, 1).Value) = Anode Then
                If WorksheetFunction.Trim(Fcst_Essbase.Cells(i, 2).Value) = LoB Then
                    If WorksheetFunction.Trim(Fcst_Essbase.Cells(i, 3).Value) = Month Then
                        If "Y" & Right(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Fcst_Essbase.Cells(i, 4).Value), 2) = Year Then
                    fcst_bal_find = Fcst_Essbase.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        fcst_bal_find = "N/A"

    End Function


    Sub balfcst_find()

        Dim fcst_tab As Worksheet
        Dim match As Variant
        Dim Anode As String
        Dim LoB As String
        Dim Month As String
        Dim Year As String
        Dim fcst_rowcnt
        Dim act_rowcnt
        
        fcst_rowcnt = Sheets("Date Dims").Range("B7")
        act_rowcnt = Sheets("Date Dims").Range("B8")
        Set fcst_tab = Sheets("Cartesian Product - Fcst")

    For i = 2 To fcst_rowcnt
        Anode = fcst_tab.Range("A" & i).Value
        LoB = fcst_tab.Range("B" & i).Value
        Month = fcst_tab.Range("C" & i).Value
        Year = fcst_tab.Range("D" & i).Value
        match = fcst_bal_find(Anode, LoB, Month, Year)
        fcst_tab.Cells(i, 5) = match ' test the output
    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Use a Variant array - [read the range in question into an array](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx), and loop the array instead of looping the cells as you are doing now.

Comment: Ok. Fastest for finding data is autofilter and followed by dictionaries. Also have you tried yes bigbens comment - looping through the array as opposd to the cells. it would be faster too.

Comment: 'AutoFilter` is not fastes @DavidWooley-AST, in my experience. It's slow and can even be buggy. Variant array is the way to go.

Comment: Ok. I agree . I was going by the times of some VBA YouTubers , an Irish man. "Excel Macro Mastery" . Depends on what process & for which purpose.  But I always like to challenge myself..

Comment: @ David Wooley - AST: You probably meant [Advanced Filter](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7ScsebMq5uV493VqnVEIY35SKxUKwWHM) and you're talking about Paul Kelly from [Excel Macro Mastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/).

Comment: Also worth pointing out that `VBA.Trim()` is orders of magnitude faster than `WorksheetFunction.Trim()` so use the former unless you really need the worksheet version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using variant array to match something from a current project of mine. You can modify to suit your needs.

```
Private Function verifyMod(modValue As Double, state As String) As Boolean
    
    If Len(modValue) Then
        
        Dim modTable As ListObject
        Set modTable = lookupsAUState.ListObjects("stateWritingCoModMinMax")
        
        Dim v As Variant
        v = modTable.DataBodyRange.value
        
        Dim company As String
        company = StrConv(xmlCo.Range("insuranceCompanyName"), vbProperCase)
        
        Dim x As Long
        For x = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        
            If v(x, modTable.ListColumns("Company").index) = company Then
            
                If v(x, modTable.ListColumns("State").index) = state Then
                    
                    If modValue >= v(x, modTable.ListColumns("Min").index) And modValue <= v(x, modTable.ListColumns("Max").index) Then
                    
                        verifyMod = True
                    
                    Else
                        
                        MsgBox state & " allows for modifications between " & v(x, modTable.ListColumns("Min").index) & " and " & v(x, modTable.ListColumns("Max").index) & ". Please enter a modification within that range."
                        
                    End If
                    
                    Exit For
                    
                End If
                
             End If
             
        Next
        
    End If
    
End Function
```